# "Cannot GET /null" when running a server with nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, html, server, multiplayer

Edit #2: Uhhhhhh, the error went away after I restarted my computer. I didn't change anything. Another fine day wasted on a bug that didn't even exist....

I guess you can delete this?

My code was working fine without any routes before, but then this started happening and I didn't commit in like a day so I don't want to load my last save. What does this mean and how can I fix it?

I don't really know what to ask because there's nothing similar to what I'm experiencing when you search for "cannot get/null nodejs" on google. I have like 500 lines of code if you want me to post it.

```
_________________________________
<!doctype html>
<html>
<body>
<div id="signDiv">
Username: <input id="signDiv-username" type="text"></input><br>
Password: <input id="signDiv-password" type="password"></input><br>
<button id="signDiv-signIn">Sign in</button>
<button id="signDiv-signUp">Sign up</button> 
</div>

<div id="gameDiv" style="display:none;">
    <canvas id="ctx" width="500" height="500" style="border:1px solid #000000;"></canvas>

    <div id="chat-text" style="width:500px; height:100px; overflow-y:scroll">
        <div>Hello</div>
    </div>

    <form id="chat-form">
        <input id="chat-input" type="text" style="width:500px"></input>
    </form>

</div>

<script src="http://cdn.socket.io/socket.io-1.4.5.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  var userip;
</script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://l2.io/ip.js?var=userip"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  document.write("Your IP is :", userip);
</script>



<script>
    var socket = io();

    //sign in/up
    var signDiv = document.getElementById('signDiv');
    var signDivUsername = document.getElementById('signDiv-username');
    var signDivSignIn = document.getElementById('signDiv-signIn');
    var signDivSignUp = document.getElementById('signDiv-signUp');
    var signDivPassword = document.getElementById('signDiv-password');

    signDivSignIn.onclick = function(){
        socket.emit('signIn',{username:signDivUsername.value,password:signDivPassword.value});
    };
    signDivSignUp.onclick = function(){
        socket.emit('signUp',{username:signDivUsername.value,password:signDivPassword.value});
    };
    socket.on('signInResponse', function(data){
        if(data.success){
            signDiv.style.display = 'none';
            gameDiv.style.display = 'inline-block';
        } else
            alert("Sign in unsuccessul.");
    });

    socket.on('signUpResponse', function(data){
        if(data.success){
            alert("Sign up successful.");
        } else
            alert("Sign up unsuccessul.");
    });



    var chatText = document.getElementById("chat-text");
    var chatInput = document.getElementById("chat-input");
    var chatForm = document.getElementById("chat-form");

    var ctx = document.getElementById("ctx").getContext("2d");
    ctx.font = "30px Arial";


    socket.on('newPositions', function (data){
        ctx.clearRect(0,0,500,500);
        for(var i=0 ; i < data.player.length; i++)
            ctx.fillText(data.player[i].number, data.player[i].x, data.player[i].y);        

        for(var i=0 ; i < data.bullet.length; i++)
            ctx.fillRect(data.bullet[i].x-5, data.bullet[i].y-5, 10, 10);       
    });

    // socket.on('hit event', function(linkbulletdata){
    //  window.location=String(linkbulletdata);
    //  signDiv.style.display = 'inline-block';
    //  gameDiv.style.display = 'none';


    // });



    socket.on('addToChat', function(data){
        chatText.innerHTML += '<div>' + data + '</div>';
    });


    socket.on('evalAnswer', function(data){
        console.log(data);
    });



    chatForm.onsubmit = function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        if(chatInput.value[0] === '/') {
            socket.emit('evalServer', chatInput.value.slice(1));
        }
        else {socket.emit('sendMsgToServerLoadGun', chatInput.value);}
        chatInput.value = '';
    }


    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("body").keydown(function(e){
              switch(e.which) {
                  case 32: //space ATTACK
                  socket.emit('keyPress', {inputId:'attack', state:true});
                  console.log('shoot');
                  break;

                  case 37: // left
                 socket.emit('keyPress', {inputId: 'left', state: true }); 
                  console.log("keycode= " + e.keyCode); 
                  break;

                  case 38: // up
                    socket.emit('keyPress', {inputId: 'up', state: true }); 
                  console.log("keycode= " + e.keyCode); 
                  break;

                  case 39: // right
                  socket.emit('keyPress', {inputId: 'right', state: true }); 
                  console.log("keycode= " + e.keyCode); 
                  break;

                  case 40: // down
                  socket.emit('keyPress', {inputId: 'down', state: true });
                  console.log("keycode= " + e.keyCode); 
                  break;

                  default: return; // exit this handler for other keys
              }
              e.preventDefault(); // prevent the default action (scroll / move caret)


        });
    });

    document.onmousemove = function(event){
        var x = -250 + event.clientX -8;
        var y = -250 + event.clientY -8;
        var angle = Math.atan2(y,x)/Math.PI*180;
        socket.emit('keyPress', {inputId:'mouseAngle', state:angle});
    }

    document.onmousedown = function(event){
        socket.emit('keyPress', {inputId:'attack', state:true});
    }

    document.onmouseup = function(event){
        socket.emit('keyPress', {inputId:'attack', state:false});
    }


    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("body").keyup(function(e){
              switch(e.which) {
                  case 32: //space
                  console.log('space');
                  socket.emit('keyPress', {inputId:'attack', state:false});
                  break;

                  case 37: // left
                 socket.emit('keyPress', {inputId: 'left', state: false }); 
                  console.log("keycode= " + e.keyCode); 
                  break;

                  case 38: // up
                    socket.emit('keyPress', {inputId: 'up', state: false }); 
                  console.log("keycode= " + e.keyCode); 
                  break;

                  case 39: // right
                  socket.emit('keyPress', {inputId: 'right', state: false }); 
                  console.log("keycode= " + e.keyCode); 
                  break;

                  case 40: // down
                  socket.emit('keyPress', {inputId: 'down', state: false }); 
                  console.log("keycode= " + e.keyCode); 
                  break;

                  default: return; // exit this handler for other keys
              }
              e.preventDefault(); // prevent the default action (scroll / move caret)


        });
    });



</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I'd start by looking for anywhere that you're making a request (links, images, etc.). It looks like you're trying to generate a URL from a null value.

Comment: Can you try debugging? Add `console.log`s or whatever until you find the line that is causing the issue. Then you can narrow down your problem to the relevant code, and post that. See how to create a [mcve].

Answer (score 2):

The problem is most likely not with your node.js server code, but with your client code. I can reproduce this error if I start up an express.js server, then visit `localhost:3000/null` in the browser. The browser comes back with 'Cannot GET /null'.

So without any further information, the problem is most likely with your client code: the code that is requesting information from your node.js server. Most likely cause: it looks like one of your js objects in that client code is getting set to `null`, then that object is being used as the path for a request to the node.js server. Your server presumably doesn't have a route for `/null`, and so you see that error.

Hope that helps! Feel free to post some client-side code if I'm completely on the wrong track.

Comment: Yes you're definitely right that it's in the client. I added the client "index.html" to the OP. JSHint doesn't pick anything that solves the problem btw

Comment: nothing jumps out at me. some more details might help though - what do you do to reproduce the error message, for example? and where does the error message appear - in the console of the browser, or your server log? or in the main page of your browser?